# Autocorrelation and evidence of iid

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, iid

Suppose I have the first seven autocorrelations for some variable $x$.
And suppose they are -0.2, 0.15, -0.05, -0.10, -0.05, -0.14, 0.04

How can this be used as evidence of my data being or not being IID (suppose $n=150)$.

Comment: I've removed the tag "econometrics". Nothing here is idiosyncratic to econometrics.

Comment: Pages 19 and 20 at http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/153-fall2010/lectures/4.pdf answer this question: when your data are approximately Normal and IID, the asymptotic variances are $1/n$, implying their SDs are around $0.082$ in this case.

Comment: The term *IID* stands for '*independent and identically distributed*'. Absence of autocorrelation doesn't say *anything* about the second part, but only about a particular kind of dependence (i.e. it only addresses the first letter in 'IID'). Consequently, the values of those sample autocorrelations alone cannot allow you to make statements the plausibility of the IID assumption. You should probably edit to ask more specifically about the independence assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Are you working in R? Plot the ACF function with the confidence intervals, if one of your autocorrelation values [-0.2, 0.15, -0.05, -0.10, -0.05, -0.14, 0.04] for the first seven lags exceeds this confidence interval, you know it is significant.

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/plot.acf.html

You can also calculate it manually. The 96% confidence interval of the autocorrelation is given by [ $-1.96/ \sqrt{n}$ to $1.96/ \sqrt{n}$ ], which is in your case with n=150 [-0.16 to 0.16]. So given the autocorrelation of your first seven lags, we would conclude that there is significant correlation of an observation at time T with an observation at T-1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you only the first seven autocorrelations or are you able to compute everything you want? Have you all the values of x?

If that is the case, I guess you could try the Durbin-Watson test. It is used to detect non-null autocorrelation. There may be more information [in this pdf](https://www.google.fr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.stata.com%2Fmeeting%2Fnew-orleans13%2Fabstracts%2Fmaterials%2Fnola13-baum.pdf&ei=GVrVUqWVMPCU0QXj64DADA&usg=AFQjCNFH4xUNgbM35G-ikKIl2r0RqNU6CQ&sig2=4L8PuyOY80-nyrjDZy4JKA).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others' comments, I would advocate plotting the variogram for these data which is very effective at showing temporal or spatial sources of correlation in data. You can estimate the kernel and nuggets of such plots to determine the strength of correlation and the amount of dispersion in these data.